# How resources will be free by Dispose or Finalize?

Tags: dispose, finalize

I have three classes. Class1, Class2 and Class3. I have circular dependency(class1 to class2, class2 to class3,class3 to class1). In this case how resources will be free by dispose method or finalize()?

Comment: Do all of the classes implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: Moreover, I'm fairly certain that the order of finalization is undefined, which means that you're not going to get a precise answer. What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think you need this information in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

When you implement `IDisposable` on an object you also make a decision of ownership. If `Class1` has a reference to `Class2` you have to decide if `Class1` owns `Class2` or if it just stores a reference. If `Class1` owns `Class2` and `Class2` is `IDisposable` then `Class1` should also implement `IDisposable` and `Class1` should call `Dispose` on the `Class2` reference in the `Dispose` method, but only when called explicitely - not when finalized.

Because `IDisposable` also defines an ownership hierarchy you cannot have circular dependencies when disposing. Of course `Class1` can own `Class2` that owns `Class3` and `Class3` can have a reference to `Class1` but because `Class3` doesn't own `Class1` it should not call `Dispose` on the reference when disposed.

During finalization a class that implements `IDisposable` should only release unmanaged resources and not call `Dispose` on classes that it owns because these instances may already have been finalized by the garbage collector.

Comment: I wish .NET had made some distinction between references that encapsulate ownership and references that don't.  While there would be no way to avoid manual `Dispose` coding in some cases, it really should be possible to have a type specify that it "owns" certain fields, and have the compiler provide a way to `Dispose` all of the fields that an object owns whose types implement `IDisposable`.